# Typus static assets fail to load on Engine Yard cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, engineyard, typus

In development, the typus gem seems to link its app/assets/vendor/ to /public/vendor to load assets (css and javascript) from the gem and this works fine for me. I just deployed my code to Engine Yard Cloud and now Typus cannot find any of its assets:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   https://staging.app.com/vendor/typus/vendor/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   https://staging.app.com/vendor/typus/vendor/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   https://staging.app.com/vendor/typus/vendor/jquery-tokeninput/css/token-input.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   https://staging.app.com/vendor/typus/vendor/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

etc, etc. I know Engine Yard stores bundled gems slightly differently than my development machine but everything else seems to work fine. Does anyone know if this is an EY problem or a Typus problem, and how I might fix it? I am using Rails 3.0.11, typus 3.012, and ruby 1.9.2-p290.

EDIT:
I have worked around the solution by creating a symlink:
`ln -s /data/AppName/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/typus-3.0.12/app/assets/vendor/typus/ /data/AppName/current/public/vendor/typus` but this is just a band-aid and not a long term fix, so I still appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like typus only works wit 3.1.x and 3.2.x "Works with Rails 3.1.X and Rails 3.2.X."

https://github.com/fesplugas/typus

Comment: Hmmm, I believe those are "features" not minimum requirements. I have been using it since before Rails 3.2 existed. Also gem dependencies specify a minimum rails version for each version of typus, which is why I am running 3.012, the latest version supported for my version of rails.